# how to resize xml when open keyboard?

Tags: android, xml, keyboard

I have problem with screen size when keyboard is open. I want resize my `linearLayout` when selected edit Text and keyboard is opened
is It possible?

my xml code :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".base.BaseAppCompatActivity"
android:background="#868136d7"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/animation_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:lottie_fileName="splash.json"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/convert_back"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:text="@string/txt_toolbar_register_login"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    />




            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/logo"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/txt_register_login"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                />


            <EditText
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="@drawable/radius_edt"
                android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/phoneNumberEdt"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_mobile_confirm"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="@drawable/radius_button"
                android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                android:text="@string/register"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                />

        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my pic for example for default when keyboard is not open
pic 2 is when selected edit text and keyboard is opened
[image]
[image]

Do you think there is a solution to this issue?If so, how can it be made?

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` for your Activity.